# what is the advantages of mutivalued option in solr

Tags: solr

What is the advantages of mutivalued field option in solr.

I have a field with comma separated keywords.

I can do 2 things

1. make a non-multivalued text field
2. make a multivalued text field which contains each keyword

I can still query in both the cases. So whats the advantages of multivalued over non-multivalued?

Comment: how and why should I accept answers if I dont find answers satisfactory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

advantages of multivalued: you don't need to change the document design. If en document containes multiple values in one filed, so solr/lucen can handle this field.
Also an advantage: multiple values could describe an document more exact (thing about tags of an blog post, or so)

advantages of non-multivalued: you can use specific features, which required an single term (word) in one filed, like spell checking. It's also a benefit for clustering (carrot) or grouping, which works mostly better on non-multivalued fields

Answer (score 0):

Querying by the multivalue field will receive what you want.

Example: doc1 has a keyword 'abc', and doc2 has a keyword 'abcd'. If query by keyword 'abc' only doc1 should be matched. 
So in non-multivalue approach both documents will matched, case you'll use **like** syntax.

Comment: thats not true...abc and abcd are two different terms which are indexed..so be it multivalued or not, only abc will be matched

Comment: how will look your query expression to match a keyword 'abc' for non-multivalue approach? For simplicity I put a single keyword, but both documents can have other keywords associated ...

Answer (score 0):

multivalue fields can be very handy,  let say you have many fields and you wish to search for several fields but not in all of them. you can create multivalue field that include all the fields that you wont to search for them on this field and search in it.
for example, let say you have fields that may have value of string or value of number. and than you wish to search on all string values that were found in the document. so you can create multivalue field for all string values and search in it.